# Take method argument as an argument in the annotation in Java 8

Tags: java, oop, java-8, annotations, java-annotations

I have looked up and till now it doesn't seem possible, so, if that's the case, what is the best alternative to meet the following requirement?

```
@Authentication_Annotation(id, password)
public void method(String id, String password, String param) {
    // Does something if ID and Password are correct.
}
```

Coming from a python background, this would have been possible using decorators.
Can we still do it in java, without calling a method that authenticates every time a method needs to be provided authentication?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. You cannot use a method in an annotation, as you said yourself. The syntax you used for your annotation is wrong; they must be compile-time constants. I also fail to see how "id" or "password" could be interpreted as a method.

Comment: It’s even unclear why you want that. What is the expected effect of that annotation? This annotation is not used anywhere and for [whatever you *actually* want to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), changing the place where you use the annotation instead of the method arguments to just use the method arguments, is the simpler solution.

Comment: You might want to look at AOP, e.g. with AspectJ: https://medium.com/@hasithalgamge/annotations-with-aspect-e2942dc9161c . That way you can access the parameters and verify them before the `method` actually gets called.

Comment: @Michael I meant, method argument.

Comment: @Holger I want to check whether the used ID and password is correct. This will be done in multiple places, in a lot of classes. I can create a utility method but I wanted something like annotation to make it clean.

What I'm trying to ask is, what is the best way to go about it?

Comment: @BugsBuggy Correct according to what? The hardcoded username and password in the annotation? They would have to be hardcoded to be placed in an annotation, because the args must be compile-time constants. It's unclear to me why you are persuing using an annotation in the first place. You could do the same thing with a method. In each method, call some common `auth` method as the first statement. It's the same number of lines, and much more flexible. I fail to see what value you think annotations are adding here. Seems the wrong tool for the job

Comment: @BugsBuggy and how does an annotation check whether user ID and password are correct?

Comment: The annotation will basically fetch the password of that ID from a service, and then check if the passwords match. 
An annotation would have made it clearer to distinguish if a function is a protected one or an open one for something who's just going through the code.

Calling another function as the first line will work just as fine.

Comment: An annotation is just meta-information. An annotation will not do anything. An annotation will not fetch something from a service and an annotation will not perform checks. Actual code will do. Depending on how that code is organized, it may be able to search for annotated methods, so marking a method as being intended to have password protection is fine. Trying to bring method arguments into an annotation, is pointless. An annotation doesn’t do things, hence, it doesn’t need to receive arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access method args directly in your annotation instead of passing it as arguments explicitly.

Using AOP:
[Get method arguments using Spring AOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660535/get-method-arguments-using-spring-aop)

Anyways there seems to be another way via reflection using DynamicProxy:
[Java method missing (ala Ruby) for decorating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541554/java-method-missing-ala-ruby-for-decorating)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in Java (at least without ungodly amount of very dark black magic).